# Textarea - new lines to br tags and then special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area with the following id: `#openingHours`

The text area contains information, for example:

```
<textarea id="openingHours">
    Mon-Fri 8am - 6pm
    Sat-Sun 9am - 3pm
</textarea>
```

I want to get the value of the textarea and replace new lines with break tags.

```
Mon-Fri 8am - 6pm<br/>Sat-Sun 9am - 3pm
```

Notice how it is all on one line.

How can I achieve this? All of the data must be on the same line, separated by 
 tags and html encoded to special characters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace `\n` with `<br/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/eBHgc/2/

```
<textarea id="openingHours">
    Mon-Fri 8am - 6pm
    Sat-Sun 9am - 3pm
</textarea>
```

```
var content = $('#openingHours').html().replace('\n', '<br/>');
```

Comment: But this is inside a text area, and there is no HTML in the text area, I simply want to replace new lines with br tags and then encode the output and pass it to a variable.

Comment: @user1088771 - updated my answer. Your question did not sound anything like how you just explained it.

Comment: I'm guessing `replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')` will work as a global match. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
string htmlEncoded = Server.HtmlEncode(text);
```

In javascript do

```
function htmlEncode(value)
{   
return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
}
```

sorry didnt see the javascript at first.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really JavaScript.

Comment: He's using JavaScript, not C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the following as an html and see how the line break in textarea works,
tested on IE and Chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(foo)
{
 var spvNotStr = "line1<br>line2<br>line3<br>"; 
 var mySplitResult = spvNotStr.split("<br>");
    for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
        
         document.forms[0].elements['foo'].value +=  mySplitResult[i]+'\n';
    }
}
</script>


<form action="#">
<textarea name="foo" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<hr />
<a href="#" onclick="changeValue('bar');">click</a>
</form>
```

Comment: OP wants just the opposite, `replace new lines with break tags`